# extract item from dictionary in dictionary with for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

i wanna append an element of dictionary in dictionary into list with for loop, but i["fruit"] seems like an indices. How can i fix ?

```
dict_1 = {"number_1": {"fruit": ['banana'],
                 "no": ['1']
                },
      "number_2": {"fruit": ['apple'],
                 "no": ['2']
                }
    }

list_1 = [i["fruit"] for i in dict_1["number_1"]]
print list_1
# print dict_1["number_1"]["fruit"]
```

Comment: i know but i wanna extract dict_1's element

Comment: try `list_1 = [v["fruit"] for k,v in dict_1.items()]`

Comment: do you want `[['apple'], ['banana']]` or just info for `number_1` ? this is not clear.

Comment: i want this ['banana']. just for dict_1

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is you iterate over `dict_1['number_1'` - which returns only the keys of that dictionary:

```
for item in dict_1['number_1']:
    print item
fruit
no
```

If you want to iterate the values as well, you need to add `.items()`:

```
for item, value in dict_1['number_1'].items():
    print item
fruit ['banana']
no ['1']
```

So if you want just the banana, iterate your dictionary with `dict_1['number_1'].items()` and append to the list the `value` part:

```
list1 = []
for item, value in dict_1['number_1'].items():
    list1.append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't only get  ['banana'] directly of 'number_1' because the dictionary is unordered in python, and  we don't know which key, value pair is appearing and that's why we don't know when 'number_1' will appear and when 'number_2' as the first key, value pair.

There are two possible solutions with unordered dictionary :

> the first solution get all fruit names :

```
dict_1 = {"number_1": {"fruit": ['banana'],
                 "no": ['1']
                },
      "number_2": {"fruit": ['apple'],
                 "no": ['2']
                }
    }

for key,value in dict_1.items():
    print(value['fruit'])
```

> second is

if you especially want banana then first check the key because as I said dictionary are unordered.

```
for key,value in dict_1.items():
    if key=='number_1':
        print(value['fruit'])
```

Other solution is if you don't want to check key then use ordered dictionary from collection module :

```
from collections import OrderedDict

my_dict=OrderedDict()
my_dict['number_1'] = OrderedDict()

my_dict['number_1']['fruit']=['banana']
my_dict['number_1']['no']=['1']



my_dict['number_2']=OrderedDict()
my_dict['number_2']['fruit']=['apple']
my_dict['number_2']['no']=['2']


print(list(list(my_dict.values())[0].values())[0])
```

output:

```
['banana']
```